# React hooks not returning updated state values inside callback function from library events (FabricJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I am not getting the updated state values inside FabricJS events like object:modified, mouse:up, etc... But I can able to set state value inside that callback functions.

When I tried to get the state value, it is returning the initial values and not the updated one.

**Example:**

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

The initial value is 0. I update the value using setCount to 1. Whenever I tried to get the "count" inside the callback function, it is returning 0 or the initial value.

Edit:

What I am trying to achieve is that I am trying to save FabricJS object whenever object modified (For Undo, Redo operations). Whenever an object changes, FabricJS is triggering an event and calls a function in the component. But I don't get the state value.

Code:

```
function MyFunction()
{
   const [canvasObj, setCanvasObj] = useState({});
   const [state, setCanvasState] = useState('');
   const [undo, setUndo] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {

      if(Object.keys(canvasObj).length == 0) {
         var _canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
            preserveObjectStacking: true,
         });

         setCanvasObj(_canvas);

         _canvas.on("object:modified", saveState);
      }
   });

   function saveState() {
       console.log(canvasObj); // Returns null even though object initialised
       if (state) { // state value returns null. Due to this, I can't get the existing data and push the current state
          let newState = undo;
          newState.push(state);
          setUndo(newState);
       }
       const tmpState = JSON.stringify(canvasObj);
       setCanvasState(tmpState);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setCount(prev => prev +1)?

Comment: I need to check the count value before calling setCount. If I call "setCount", it is working. But not able to get the value and compare it.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that I am trying to save FabricJS object whenever object modified. Whenever object changes, it is triggering an event from FabricJS and that calls a function in the component. But I don't get the state inside that function

Comment: please add more relevant code to your question, how do you call `setCount` and where you want to get the data unsuccessfully

Comment: @HagaiHarari Sorry, just now added my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the general example on how can you save canvas state inside react component. You need a separate variable to keep track of canvas history changes:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { fabric } from "fabric";

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState();
  // Array of objects, that represents canvas state history
  const [canvasHistory, setCanvasHistory] = useState([initialState]);
  const [canvasState, setCanvasState] = useState(initialState);

  const onObjectModified = useCallback(
    e => {
      const newCanvasState = e.target.canvas.toJSON();
      setCanvasState(newCanvasState);
      // Limit history depth
      setCanvasHistory(history => [...history, newCanvasState].slice(-4));
    },
    [setCanvasState, setCanvasHistory]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current);
    canvas.loadFromJSON(initialState);

    canvas.on("object:modified", onObjectModified);
    setCanvas(canvas);

    // Don't forget to destroy canvas and remove event listeners on component unmount
    return () => canvas.dispose();
  }, [canvasRef, onObjectModified, setCanvas]);

  const moveHistory = useCallback(
    step => {
      const currentStateIndex = canvasHistory.indexOf(canvasState);
      const prevState = canvasHistory[currentStateIndex + step];
      canvas.loadFromJSON(prevState);
      setCanvasState(prevState);
    },
    [canvas, canvasState, canvasHistory, setCanvasState]
  );

  const onUndo = useCallback(() => moveHistory(-1), [moveHistory]);

  const onRedo = useCallback(() => moveHistory(1), [moveHistory]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onUndo} disabled={canvasHistory[0] === canvasState}>
        Undo
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={onRedo}
        disabled={canvasHistory[canvasHistory.length - 1] === canvasState}
      >
        Redo
      </button>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} width="300" height="300" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Also, I made a minimal working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/retain-fabricjs-state-bi9sk)

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is it possible to add a new const to push the states, so that when user click on "Undo" or "Redo", I will show that state accordingly? I have updated my code. If you look at that, you can see, I can't able to get the previous data and push it.

Comment: It is possible, but you have to keep previous state in a separate variable to be able to invoke `loadFromJSON` with it. Updated my sandbox example.